# Rails routes url take out user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I currently have the standard

`get 'profile/:id/view', to: 'profile#view', as: 'view'`

which produces `http://localhost:3000/profile/233/view`

the controller is

```
def view
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

How can I make a path that the url is `http://localhost:3000/profile/view` - leaving out the URL?

I was trying to do something like

```
def view(user_id)
        @user = User.find(user_id)
end
```

But I'm not sure how to write that in the routes, or what the link_to path would look like for that?

I have been looking for a straight forward answer, but have not been able to find one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I couldn't understand this: "How can I make a path that the url is /profile/view - leaving out the URL?"

Comment: @Saibot I was being lazy - i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the route to

```
get 'profile/view', to: 'profile#view'
```

And then in the controller, you can user `current_user` method which devise provides.

```
def view
  @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Rockwell Rice - What about if it's not the current_user? What if a user clicks on another user to go to their profile?

Comment: @gwalshington You have to provide the `user_id` in some way. If the action is  a  `GET` there is no alternative, if for some reason you can make it into a `POST` call then you can send data them as params which doesn't show up in the url.

Comment: 'You have to provide the user_id in some way'  I can not pass the id in any way except the URL?

Comment: Like @aks said  you can either use a `POST` where data is passed "quietly" in a get in the URL. BUT --- It doesn't have the be the numerical id from the database, it can also be a parameterized slug.  If that interests you, look at FriendlyFind -- https://github.com/norman/friendly_id -- that way you can, as @rockwell-rice said , you can view the params[:user_id] OR `current_user`